# Regex to read the id

Tags: regex, perl

I have the log file with the following content:

```
 (2947:_dRW00T3WEeSkhZ9pqkt5dQ) ---$ ABC XY "Share" 16-Sep-2014 03:22 PM
 (2948:_3nFSwz3TEeSkhZ9pqkt5dQ) ---$ ABC XY "Share" 16-Sep-2014 03:05 PM
 (2949:_voeYED3AEeSkhZ9pqkt5dQ) ---$ ABC XY "Initial for Re,oved" 16-Sep-2014 12:44 PM
```

I want to read the unique id say _dRW00T3WEeSkhZ9pqkt5dQ from each line and store it in a array.
My current code is:

```
while(<$fh>) {
            if ($_ =~ /\((.*?)\)/) {
                push @cs_ids , $1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    while(<$fh>) {
        if ($_ =~ /\(\d+:(.+?)\)/) {
            push @cs_ids , $1;
        }
    }
```

The regexp checks all string which starts with `(` then one or more digits a double point and than one or more characters ( Which will be stored in `$1`). THe end of the string is a `)`.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
perl -e '$string = "(2947:_dRW00T3WEeSkhZ9pqkt5dQ)"; if ($string =~ /^\((\d+:)(.*?)\)$/) { die $2; }'
_dRW00T3WEeSkhZ9pqkt5dQ at -e line 1.
```

Change your regular expression condition to:

```
/^\((\d+:)(.*?)\)$/
```

What that does is match and group the 4 digits and colon into special var $1 and the id you want into special var $2.

Answer (score 0):

If every line of the log file is guaranteed to have an ID string, then you can write just

```
while (<$fh>) {
  /:(\w+)/ and push @cs_ids , $1;
}
```

The `\w` ("word") character class matches alphanumeric characters or underscore, and this regex just snags the  first sequence of word characters that follow a colon. It is best to avoid the non-greedy modifier if possible as it is a sloppy specification and can be much slower than a simple multiple character match.